# Merge and match objects that match AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hello I would like to merge and match two json objects.  I would like to do with the Angular way.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you everyone.  Here is an example:

```
    // First json object
    {
       "UserID":"john.davis",
       "edpi":null,
       "UserApp":[
          {
             "Name":"name3",
             "Link":"/Protect3.php"
          },
          {
             "Name":"name5",
             "Link":"/Admin/Launch.html"
          },
          {
             "Name":"name2",
             "Link":"aaap/defaultBH.php"
          }
       ]
    }

    // Second json object

    [
          {
             "color":"color1",
             "icon": "content/images/icons/administrator.svg",
             "Name": "name5"
          },
          {
             "color":"color3",
             "icon": "content/images/icons/administrator.svg",
             "Name": "name3"
          },
          {
             "color":"color2",
             "icon": "content/images/icons/behavior.svg",
             "Name": "name2"

          }
       ]
```

Hoping to get this

```
    [
       {
          "TokenName":"name3",
          "TokenLink":"../Protect3.asp",
          "color":{
             "color":"color3",
             "icon": "content/images/icons/administrator.svg",
             "match": "name3"
          }
       },
       {
           "Name":"name5",
             "Link":"/Admin/Launch.html",
          "color":{
              "color":"color1",
             "icon": "content/images/icons/administrator.svg",
             "match": "name5"
          }
       },
       {
             "Name":"name2",
             "Link":"aaap/defaultBH.php"
          "color":{
             "color":"color2",
             "icon": "content/images/icons/behavior.svg",
             "match": "name2"
          }
       }
    ]
```

Comment: Do elaborate on what you are trying to achieve in the question

Comment: In my current code, I have successfully merged both objects.  But now I would like to merge the matching object properties.  Here is the code below of what I did to merge the two objects.

Comment: First I pulled both both json objects using Angular http.  Then I wrote a function to push objects from second object to the first.                                                                                                              function addColor (objectArray, colorArray, restrictedtemplate){
 objectArray.forEach(function(object, index){

  object.color = colorArray[index];

 });
};
addColor($scope.restrictedapps, $scope.colors, $scope.unrestricteddata);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Here is the code below.

```
    function mergeArraysOnProperty(array1, array2, property) {
      array1.forEach(function(element1) {
        array2.forEach(function(element2) {
          if (element1[property] === element2[property]) {
            for (var newProperty in element2) {
              if (element2.hasOwnProperty(newProperty)) {
                element1[newProperty] = element2[newProperty];
              }
            }
          }
        });
      });
      return array1;
    };

    $scope.newjson = mergeArraysOnProperty(userapp, color, "Name");

    console.log($scope.newjson);
```